# Magetno how add checkbox in contact form?

Tags: magento, checkbox

I must add checkbox in Contact form in Magetno (Magento wer. 1.8.1), I searching tutorials on Google but I found solution ... It is easy way to do this ?

Many Thanks
Wojtek

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

why you don't use the checkout agreements: Just fetch the agreements in file \app\design\frontend\PACKAGE\TEMPLATE\template\contacts\form.phtml by

```
if (Mage::getStoreConfigFlag('checkout/options/enable_agreements')) {

                $agreements = Mage::getModel('checkout/agreement')->getCollection()

                               ->addStoreFilter(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())

                               ->addFieldToFilter('is_active', 1); 
}
```

and print out some or all of them like

```
if ($agreements) {

                foreach ($agreements as $_a):

                               // ID 5 = Datenschutz-Agreement deutsch, ID 6 = Alter-18-Agreement englisch, ID 7 = Datenschutz-Agreement deutsch, ID 8 = Alter-18-Agreement englisch

                               if ($_a->getId() >= 7 && $_a->getId() <= 8) {

?>

                                               <li>

                                               <div class="checkout-agreements">

                                                               <div class="agreement-content"<?php echo ($_a->getContentHeight() ? ' style="height:' . $_a->getContentHeight() . '"' : '')?>>

                                                                               <?php if ($_a->getIsHtml()):?>

                                                                                              <?php echo $_a->getContent() ?>

                                                                               <?php else:?>

                                                                                              <?php echo nl2br($this->escapeHtml($_a->getContent())) ?>

                                                                               <?php endif; ?>

                                                               </div>

                                                               <p class="agree">

                                                                               <input type="checkbox" id="agreement-<?php echo $_a->getId()?>" name="agreement[<?php echo $_a->getId()?>]" value="1" title="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_a->getCheckboxText()) ?>" class="required-entry checkbox" /><label for="agreement-<?php echo $_a->getId()?>"><?php echo $_a->getIsHtml() ? $_a->getCheckboxText() : $this->escapeHtml($_a->getCheckboxText()) ?></label>

                                                               </p>

                                               </div>

                                               </li>

<?php

                               }             

                endforeach;

}
```

That's all!

If there is someone German here: [There](https://www.econcess.de/blog/onlineshop-erstellung-magento/158-magento-datenschutz-checkbox-fuer-kontaktformular-und-registrierung) you will get the full explanation in German!

Best regards

Bastian